# startActivity skips onCreate()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple case of `Activity1 -> Activity2`.

In the past when I've used `startActivity(Intent(this, Activity2::class.java))` there have been no issues and the `onCreate()` method of `Activity2` would be called.

In my current case this is not happening. I have logs in the `onCreate()` method and they are never hit. But if I create a `onStart()` method it enters there. However, never in my logs for the lifetime of the application does `onCreate()` of `Activity2` ever get hit. How is this possible. `onCreate` is a requirement before `onStart` I thought.

Here is the actual code I'm referencing above.

```
class Activity1 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Timber.d("onCreate")

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        startActivity(Activity2.getIntent(this))
    }
}
```

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        Timber.d("onCreate") // Never gets touched
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Timber.d("onStart"); // Is hit with no problems.
    }

    companion object {
        fun getIntent(@NonNull context: Context) : Intent {
            return Intent(context, Activity2::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You overrode the wrong `onCreate` - you do not want to use the `PersistableBundle` version. Change your `onCreate` to only take the `savedInstanceState: Bundle?` parameter:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Timber.d("onCreate") // Now it'll be called
}
```

Comment: Damn... I feel so dumb :( Should I just delete this question? I don't know how I messed that up.

Comment: Nah, it'll probably help someone else down the line that runs into the exact same problem. Easy to miss when you've been staring at it for too long :)

Comment: It literally just saved my ass, thanks for not deleting this!